# evollu/react-native-fcm - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, notifications, react-native-fcm

My App runs well, but... when it recives a notification from Firebase it Crash.

I think it's happening because my configuration is bad since i had implemented the "react-native-fcm" example.

I getFCMToken() succesfull.

Do you look any error? Do you know why is happening it? Ideas? HelP!!

[CONSOLE ERRORS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3ye5.png)

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^4.8.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-firebase-storage-connector": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.47",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.7.0",
    "react-native-fcm": "^13.3.1",
    "react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.8",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.26.7",
    "react-native-modal": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-responsive-image": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-side-menu": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-textinput-effects": "^0.4.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.5.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "slugify": "^1.2.9"
},
```

app/build.gradlew

```
      compileSdkVersion 27
      buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"

      defaultConfig {
          applicationId "com.reactnavigationdrawer"
          minSdkVersion 16
          targetSdkVersion 22
          versionCode 1
          versionName "1.0"
          ndk {
              abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
          }
      }

  dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
      compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+"
      compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
      compile(project(':react-native-fbsdk')) {
       exclude(group: 'com.facebook.android', module: 'facebook-android-sdk')
      }
      compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1')
      compile ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.2.0") {
        force = true;
     }
      compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0') {
          force = true;
      }
      compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.0') {
          force = true;
      }
      compile (project(':react-native-fcm')){
          exclude group: "com.google.firebase"
      }
      compile ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.2.0") {
          force = true;
      }
      compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
      compile project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
      compile project(':react-native-image-picker')

  }

  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradlew

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.+' // <- USE 2.2.+ version
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

MainActivity.java

```
  package com.reactnavigationdrawer;

  import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
  import android.content.Intent;

  public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

      @Override
      public void onNewIntent (Intent intent) {
          super.onNewIntent(intent);
          setIntent(intent);
      }

      @Override
      public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
          MainApplication.getCallbackManager().onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      }

      @Override
      protected String getMainComponentName() {
          return "reactnavigationdrawer";
      }
  }
```

MainApplication.java

```
  @Override
  protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
     return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
        new MainReactPackage(),
        new VectorIconsPackage(),
        new ImagePickerPackage(),
        new RNFetchBlobPackage(),
        new FIRMessagingPackage(),
        new FBSDKPackage(mCallbackManager)
    );
 }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.reactnavigationdrawer"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
      <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
      <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>

      <uses-sdk
          android:minSdkVersion="16"
          android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

      <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

        <service android:name="com.evollu.react.fcm.MessagingService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
           <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
           </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name="com.evollu.react.fcm.InstanceIdService" android:exported="false">
           <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
           </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver android:name="com.evollu.react.fcm.FIRLocalMessagingPublisher"/>
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true"  android:name="com.evollu.react.fcm.FIRSystemBootEventReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity
          android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:launchMode="singleTop"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
      </application>
  </manifest>
```

if you need more information you'll tell me!

Comment: Do you get a stack trace in Logcat?

Comment: I edited the post. You can see Logcat clicking on "CONSOLE ERRORS"

Comment: how to receive notification data on log in class extends ReactActivity in android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error reads ...

> **unable to resolve** superclass of **com.evullu.react.fcm.MessagingService**

this means either reference in the `Mainfest.xml` is wrongful and / or the referenced class [com.evullu.react.fcm.MessagingService](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/evollu/react/fcm/MessagingService.java) does not exist. it might probably be rather called `com.reactnavigationdrawer.MessagingService` (or alike) and there's no need to compile the obsoleted package `play-services-gcm` either.

better add a dependency for `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0` ...which should contain the `superclass` of `com.evullu.react.fcm.MessagingService`, which cannot be resolved. you can check with  `./gradlew app:dependencies | grep firebase` whether it is present.

that file `build.gradlew` should be called `build.gradle` and Android Studio might complain about outdated versions ...meanwhile it's `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1` & `com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2`. that `force = true;` also seems useless in that context, at least don't understand what it shall do there, see [ResolutionStrategy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html).

Comment: I'm [using react-native-fmc](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm). com.evullu.react.fcm.MessagingService is called correctly in Manifest.xml. play-services-gmc deleted. In configuration guide doesn't appear nothing about "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging". I suppose because its in react-native-fmc library and i'm calling react-native-fcm. [build.gradle library exaple](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm/blob/master/Examples/simple-fcm-client/android/app/build.gradle)

Comment: @DiegoBarranco you need to add it, because this is the class you want to use... no matter what frontend libraries you use (...), it won't function unless having the `MessagingService` class baked into the package. the error massage basically says "cannot find that class". while having the source code of the `react-native-fcm`, you could even step into and see where it bugs out (most likely calling `super()` while the reference is not there). you have `exclude group: "com.google.firebase"` on that react package. this might also exclude the library. either remove the exclude or add it manually.

Comment: I mean, there is nothing wrong in excluding dependencies from packages and then providing them otherwise (or newer versions)... while one has to add all of them, else it won't build. most easy might be to simply build the `react-native-fcm` with v `11.8.0` (see the `build.gradle` of that project).